# ECONNRESET SFDX Deploy

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

During a deploy a have this problem on vscode. Cli throw me the message when I try to deploy a lwc.
Someone has an idea for this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Are you missing the .js-meta.xml file for the LWC?

Comment: are you behind the proxy? what do you see if you run sfdx update

Comment: ECONNRESET is a network-related error. Are you behind a corporate proxy? Can you try the deployment from a home network and confirm if it fixes the issue?